# Where does handler really post its messages to?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I'd like to know the limits and how Handlers work in Android.

I can understand why this works exactly as expected:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv;
    Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("original text");
        setContentView(tv);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText("changing from instance member handler");
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
}
```

that code, as expected, changes the TextView without complaining for being on wrong thread. i made my handler on UI thread.

however, what i don't understand is... why does THIS also work?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("original text");
    setContentView(tv);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("changing from different thread.");
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Two questions:

1) I've made my handler from a non-UI thread, but it still updates the textview without complaining about touching a view outside of UI thread. why is that? Where are my messages actually being posted to?

2) say i have 20 pieces of code like that, where i make a new `Handler` instance each time, will there ever be a problem with running off of UI thread, or a performance issue?

Note: if i made a thread inside of a thread, and instantiate the handler in that inner inner thread, THEN the TextView can't be touched there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only code inside `run()` is executed in another thread. All the initialization is done in the thread that creates the class. And the `Runnable` is created entirely inside the ui thread.

If you were to write it like

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("changing from different thread.");
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

You would get a crash because there is no looper in the thread.

Comment: sorry, your answer is correct, but the other answer just cracked me up so much that i had to upvote his answer lol!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidT. Lucky me has a master so I was able to understand it. Don't try that at home! :D